# Object is not being deleted from NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` when I try to delete object from it, object is not being deleted. And when I debug my code there is data in it.
Here is my code -

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [array copy];
// array is NSArray which contains data

[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Because you're making copy instead of mutableCopy ..... !!

Comment: How on Earth does this anything to do with Xcode, really?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will not delete object from this `array` because your `NSMutableArray` has become `Immutable`.
You're making **copy** of `NSArray` instead of it make **mutableCopy** it will work -

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [array mutableCopy];
```

Or you can also use `initWithArray:` method.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
```